# c# mvc expression to html

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, linq

Alright, so here's the deal. I would like to be able to create a custom dropdown box from an `System.Linq.Expressions.Expression` in c#. I know there are helpers, like `DropDownListFor`, but I'm not sure how to make one from scratch, or how to pull the values etc from the expression.

Essentially why I'm doing this is if you use `DropDownListFor` it will 'select' an `<option>` based on it's `value`, but I want to 'select' an option based on it's text instead. So if anyone has an idea how to do that instead, that would be great.

This is essentially what I have so far

```
public static MvcHtmlString ValidatedEditableDropDownListFor<TModel,TProperty>(
        this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper,
        Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression,
        SelectList list,
        String defaultOption,
        Object attribs)
{
    //Basically puts the strings into a html template<div>{0}{1}</div> etc.
    return GetValidatedHtml(
        htmlHelper.LabelFor(expression).ToString() ,
        htmlHelper.DropDownListFor(expression , list , defaultOption , attribs).ToString()
        ,htmlHelper.GetValidatedErrorMessage(expression),false,"EditableDropDown");
}
```

Any ideas on how I can have the `DropDownListFor` make an `<option>` selected, or how to create my own html element based on the `Expression` and `SelectList` would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not pass your list of SelectedListItems to your view with the correct one selected by it's text from your controller

Comment: because my form is one view, and i pass the model back to the view...to do that I would need to basically clone the view, and create special cases for those specific `<select>`'s

Comment: Besides, DropDownListFor somehow pulls the values out of the expression, so there must be a way.

Comment: DropDownListFor will model bind based on value. I guess I'm confused when you say you'll have to create special cases. Can't you pass a certain `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` as a property on your ViewModel sent to your view to the DropDownList? I do this all the time, maybe you do hve a special case and I don't quite understand. Can you update the question with a better example?

Comment: The best thing to ask would be, "How do I grab the data from the expression, and use it to make my own html"

Comment: right, I understand that you're trying to grab the data from the DropDownListFor, but I'm curious why you're trying to reinvent the wheel. You can pass an IEnumerable<SelectListItem> with one of the Selected properties on the SelectListItem set to true and not have to worry about rebuilding a control. I was asking for more clarification on your original comment, basically. I'm not understanding why you would have to clone your view. I've set DropDownList's values based on the Text in the past, which was why I suggested it